# How to delete AsyncApexJob with Queued status

Tags: delete, asyncapexjob

Is there a way to delete an `AsyncApexJob` with `Queued` status ?

I can't do it in the Setup because I don't have any action link available for this jobs.

I can't do it with the `purgeOldAsyncJobs()` method because it doesn't clear jobs with this status.

And I can't do it with Developer console because after listing this jobs, if I try to delete them I got this error message :

> [object Object]: insufficient access rights on object id

I'm connected as System Administrator.

Any ideas to do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's queued that implies its scheduled, therefore you should be able to get the Job ID and abort it, e.g.

```
System.abortJob(jobId);
```

Answer (score 12):

In case Phil's solution doesn't work, and you are stuck with a zombie Queued AsyncApexJob, here's a workaround:

---

At Version 39.0, an attempt to delete a zombie Queued `AsyncApexJob` that has no associated CronTrigger using

`System.abortJob(theAsyncApexJobId)`

fails with:

> System.StringException: You can’t abort scheduled Apex jobs by calling
>   System.abortJob with an AsyncApexJob ID. Call System.abortJob with the
>   parent CronTrigger ID

But, if you go into Workbench and downgrade to Version 31.0 (other versions may work as well)

and execute

`System.abortJob(theAsyncApexJobId)`

It works! and the `AsyncApexJob's` status is switched to `Aborted`.

This is a huge plus especially for developers without Premier Support who otherwise might not get any SFDC assistance on this issue in a sandbox or DE.

Comment: @PhilHawthorn - I tried your solution (v39), which killed the `CronTrigger` but left the `AsyncApexJob` as a zombie. Not sure why.

Comment: you need to go back to v31.  I just confirmed this is working